# loading No. in mysql database into a textbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, button, textbox

The following code segment is used by me to load the contents in the database as a table!(each row has a button with value load!

```
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo"


    <tr id='rowNum'>
    <td >".$row['No.']."</td>
    <td >".$row['NIC']."</td>
    <td >".$row['DP']."</td>
    <td >".$row['DPTime']."</td>
    <td >".$row['Telephone']."</td>
<td> <input type='button' id='load'  class='btn btn-success' value='Load number' disabled=' '></td>
</tr>";
}
```

I also have the following  text box on the same web page(outside the above table)!

```
echo "<input type=text name="display number">"
```

when i press the load button of the the relevant row of the table i want to display the No. of that row in the text box! how can i achieve this?

Comment: Matching quotes mark issue.

Comment: Look at the code colorisation, its a dead giveaway

Comment: I bet if you looked in your PHP Error log it would be telling you something useful!!!

Comment: sorry it was a mistake! please help me and answer my question!

Comment: Do you REALLY have a column with the name `OrderNo.` ??With a dot in it??

Comment: sorry the name of the column is No.

Comment: Do you REALLY have a column in your database with the name `No.` ??With a dot at the end of it??

Comment: yes! please tell me hoe to load that No. to the text box when the button of thet row is clicked

Comment: Do you have `<form>` on that page

Comment: yes! the text box is in the form how can iload it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code you posted. I'll do my best to get you on your way... You will want to do what you have described with JavaScript which runs on the client. Many people use libraries these days to work with JavaScript but to avoid added confusion I will recommend looking into jQuery and write my solution in the native code.

```html
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo("
      <tr id='rowNum".$row['No.']."'>
        <td>".$row['No.']."</td>
        <td>".$row['NIC']."</td>
        <td>".$row['DP']."</td>
        <td>".$row['DPTime']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Telephone']."</td>
        <td> 
          <input type='button' id='load".$row['No.']."' onClick='javascript:document.getElementById(\"displayNumber\").value=this.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML;' class='btn btn-success' value='Load Number'>
        </td>
      </tr>"
    );
}
```

One big talking point is that you need to make sure that if you assign an id to any HTML element, unless it is a collection then that ID must be unique, otherwise your HTML will be just as invalid as your id. Also: Don't use spaces in names or ids. Just don't.

Finally, to fix up the input which is outside the table where you want the number to dynamically appear:

```html
echo("<input type='text' name='displayNumber' id='displayNumber'>");
```